# PyTorch RuntimeError: requires_grad_ is not supported on ScriptModules

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm running Python code from an old repo that seems to no longer work but I can't figure out why or how to fix it.

**SETUP CODE** (Google Colab Notebook)

```
#@title Setup
import pkg_resources
print(pkg_resources.get_distribution("torch").version)
from IPython.utils import io
with io.capture_output() as captured:
  !git clone https://github.com/openai/CLIP
  # !pip install taming-transformers
  !git clone https://github.com/CompVis/taming-transformers.git
  !rm -Rf clipit
  !git clone https://github.com/mfrashad/clipit.git
  !pip install ftfy regex tqdm omegaconf pytorch-lightning
  !pip install kornia
  !pip install imageio-ffmpeg   
  !pip install einops
  !pip install torch-optimizer
  !pip install easydict
  !pip install braceexpand
  !pip install git+https://github.com/pvigier/perlin-numpy

  # ClipDraw deps
  !pip install svgwrite
  !pip install svgpathtools
  !pip install cssutils
  !pip install numba
  !pip install torch-tools
  !pip install visdom

  !pip install gradio

  !git clone https://github.com/BachiLi/diffvg
  %cd diffvg
  # !ls
  !git submodule update --init --recursive
  !python setup.py install
  %cd ..
  
  !mkdir -p steps
  !mkdir -p models
import sys
sys.path.append("clipit")
```

**THEN ERRORS ON SECOND TO LAST INE**

```
import clipit
# To reset settings to default
clipit.reset_settings()
# You can use "|" to separate multiple prompts
prompts = "underwater city"
# You can trade off speed for quality: draft, normal, better, best
quality = "normal"
# Aspect ratio: widescreen, square
aspect = "widescreen"
# Add settings
clipit.add_settings(prompts=prompts, quality=quality, aspect=aspect)
# Apply these settings and run
settings = clipit.apply_settings()
clipit.do_init(settings) # generates error
clipit.do_run(settings)
```

> Working with z of shape (1, 256, 16, 16) = 65536 dimensions. loaded
> pretrained LPIPS loss from taming/modules/autoencoder/lpips/vgg.pth
> VQLPIPSWithDiscriminator running with hinge loss. Restored from
> models/vqgan_imagenet_f16_16384.ckpt
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 12 # Apply these settings and run
> 13 settings = clipit.apply_settings()
> ---> 14 clipit.do_init(settings)
> 15 clipit.do_run(settings)
>
> 1 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/jit/_script.py
> in fail(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 912     def _make_fail(name):
> 913         def fail(self, *args, **kwargs):
> --> 914             raise RuntimeError(name + " is not supported on ScriptModules")
> 915
> 916         return fail
>
> RuntimeError: requires_grad_ is not supported on ScriptModules

Comment: Pytorch things that end with an underscore _ work in-place. Can you try using requires_grad? (No underscore at the end)

Comment: hi! I tried that can got this error: `AttributeError: 'RecursiveScriptModule' object has no attribute 'requires_grad' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any unlucky soul that comes accross this issue this URL saved my soul

```
https://github.com/mfrashad/text2art/issues/5
```